# Memory Read into PCIe non-transparent switch device

Tags: 22.04, ram, busybox, pcie

I am not sure this is the right place for my question.

```
busybox devmem ADDRESS 32
```

into a PCIe device memory (PCIe device is an EndPoint of non-transparent PCIe switch).
From the PCI TLP transactions, the memory is read correctly. But it returns `0xFFFFFFFF` from the above shell command.

```
$busybox devmem ADDRESS 32
0xFFFFFFFF
```

Is Ubuntu 22.04 rejecting the result or is the MemRd PCIe TLP not completed?